# Remove one item from an array when clicked by only js

Tags: javascript, arrays, removechild

I am new to JavaScript. I have a small code that creates list from input and then adds it to an array. I am able to remove one item from the DOM when the item is clicked, but I couldn't remove it from the array.

I tried to use `array.splice(item, 1)`

```
lists.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.target.closest("li").remove();
    userInputArr.splice(item, 1);});
```

But it removes the entire array sometime, and sometime removes the last item. when I console log the code, it looks like I clicked 3 or 4 times on the list even though I just clicked once. I have no idea what's wrong. this is the entire code:

```
const lists = document.querySelector(".lists");
const userInput = document.querySelector(".add-note");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

userInputArr = [];

function addNote() {
  if (userInput.value < 1) {
    return;
  }
  lists.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<li class='list'>${userInput.value}</li>`
  );
  userInputArr.push(lists);

  lists.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.target.closest("li").remove();
    userInputArr.splice(item, 1);
  });
  userInput.value = "";
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  addNote();
});
```

Comment: you should not push the whole list into the array, also where is `item` coming from? for me it looks like its undefined

Comment: I solved something similar, but used a different approach. I gave each element from the list an ID, and when the parent was clicked, I went searching for the corresponding child ID and removed that one from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Code is totally meaningless

1)

```
userInputArr.push(lists)
```

why you push the same element all the time? As lists refers to the first and the only element with class 'lists'?

2)

```
userInputArr.splice(item, 1)
```

please watch carefully what splice does? The first argument is number, but you pass a collection of elements with class 'list'. But i camn not even suggest which element should be removed as it contains the same element as i mentioned in first point

3) You do not need this array at all

So right approach is something like this

```
const lists = document.querySelector(".lists");

// just once create listener, no need to do it each time
lists.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  // if you want to remove clicked item then
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') e.target.remove(); 

  // but if you want to remove the first one then uncomment line
  // if (this.children[0]) this.children[0].remove()
});

const userInput = document.querySelector(".add-note");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// item is meaninglee here, so delete this line
// const item = document.querySelectorAll(".list");

//////////////////////
// array is useless too, delete this line
// userInputArr = [];

function addNote() {
  // check if it is number
  if (isNaN(userInput.value) || Number(userInput.value < 1)) {
    return;
  }

  lists.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<li class='list'>${userInput.value}</li>`
  );

  userInput.value = "";
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  addNote();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = (() => {
  const _items = {};
  let key = 0;

  return {
    put(value) {
      _items[key++] = value;

      console.log("Added", this.all());

      return key - 1;
    },
    remove(key) {
      delete _items[key++];
      console.log("Removed", this.all());
    },
    all(asArray = true) {
      return asArray ? Object.values(_items) : { ..._items
      };
    }
  }
})();

const inputEl = document.querySelector(".input");
const itemsEl = document.querySelector(".items");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-add");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const value = inputEl.value.trim();

  if (!value.length) return;

  const key = items.put(value);
  const li = document.createElement("li");

  li.textContent = value;
  li.dataset.key = key;

  itemsEl.append(li);

  inputEl.value = "";
});

itemsEl.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const li = e.target.closest("li");

  items.remove(li.dataset.key);

  li.remove();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="btn-add">Add</button>

<ul class="items"></ul>
```

Run code & View in full screen.

Answer (score -1):

use `shift()` `userInputArr.shift()`
you are also getting double clicks because your `addNote()` function contains an event listener `lists.addEventListener` and it's executed by another event listner  `addBtn.addEventListener` you should probably move 
`lists.addEventListener` out of the `addNote` function